# One dimensional map

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I have the 1D map $x_{n+1}=Log(x_n)$. I have noticed that when an iterate becomes negative, the orbit becomes complex. Had never seen this before. What happens to the orbit that starts at some $x_0$ such that $x_n<0$ for some $n>0$, since in that case $x_{n+1}=Log(x_n)$ will be complex valued? Does the orbit terminate at the negative iterate? Thanks!

Comment: As $\ln(x)\le\frac xe$, you will always reach the interval $(0,1]$ and then negative numbers in the next step after a finite number of iterations. Note that the complex logarithm is  multi-valued, what you see as result is the main branch.

Comment: I see. So the orbit terminates as a real-value object (?)